# How can I reset sculpting in Blender?

Tags: sculpting

I am pretty new in Blender and I am working on a wrestling match. My question is, how can I reset a sculpt? A character took a side punch to her belly and I made with sculpting a punching/hole/impact effect. But I want to reset it to go further to the next shot.

I am so new that I don't really understand all the options and where to find them all.
[image]

Comment: If you want to come back to the previous shape you need to use shape keys, the basic shape key being the default shape of your object

Comment: Can i just find it or do i need to make it? Because i don’t really get it. Sorry, i am not really familiar with blender

Answer (score 0):

In the *Object Data* panel, under *Shape Keys*, create at least 2 shape keys, select the second one and put the *Value* at 1, never modify the first one so that you keep the original shape:

[image]

In Sculpt mode, change your shape as much as wanted:

[image]

Back to *Object* mode, now you can switch from the basic shape key to the second one, if you need animate, just put some keyframes on the *Value*:

[image]

Comment: ah yes, it worked but i'v found a second problemXD. when i try to sculpt. the sculpt won't work so i apply the subdivision and then i get a error. (modifier cannot be applied to a mesh with shape keys).

Comment: It's not clear why you can't sculpt, do you mean that your object had not enough topology? In that case, yes, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier and apply. As you can't apply a modifier if your mesh has shape keys, you need to remove the shape keys, apply the modifier, then give it shape keys again

Comment: A quick question, do you maybe have discord? It’s much easier to talk to if you want to ofcours

Comment: Sure, use this one and ask for moonboots:  https://discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S